# Método para tirar vida do Player não funciona

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou fazendo um *script* para *tirar vida do player* quando algo colidir com ele, já revisei o código dezenas de vezes e não encontro o erro.

O código de colisão está atrelado aos inimigos:

```c-sharp
PlayerHealth ph; 
public int danoAtaque = 10;

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    ph = gameObject.AddComponent<PlayerHealth> ();

    if (other.tag == "Player") 
    {
        Debug.Log ("Entrou no Player");
        ph.TakeDamage(danoAtaque);
        Debug.Log ("Tirou vida");

        if (ph.vidaAtual <= 0) 
        {
            Instantiate (playerExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
            gameController.GameOver ();
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
            Debug.Log ("Morreu");
        }
     }

    if (other.tag == "Boundary" || other.tag == "Enemy") {
        return;
    }

    if (explosion != null) {
        Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
    gameController.AddScore(scoreValue);        
    Destroy (gameObject);

}
```

Este outro código é o que está no Player:

```c-sharp
static int vidaInicial = 100;
public int vidaAtual;

public Slider healthSlider;
public Image damageImage;
public float flashSpeed = 5f;
public Color flashColour = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f);

void Awake ()
{
    vidaAtual = vidaInicial;
}

public void TakeDamage (int amount)
{
    Debug.Log("Chamou Funçao");
    vidaAtual -= amount;
    Debug.Log("Deu Dano");   
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), "Vida: " + vidaAtual);
}
```

Comment: Rafa Arruda, editei a tua pergunta, retirei algumas *tags* e mudei o título, se você quiser, pode [revertê-la](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/66066/revisions). Ou [editá-la](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/66066/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns errinhos, e algumas coisas que poderiam melhorar.

Eu recomendo dar [uma olhada neste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YERVEfntUXI)que vai ajudar um bocado quanto o assunto, e resolver todos os teus problemas.

Algumas orientações:

**1.**

```
ph = gameObject.AddComponent<PlayerHealth> ();
```

Você está adicionando um componente sempre que você tromba com algo.
Eu recomendo você primeiro verificar se é o player, e ser for você você pega o PlayerHealth dele.

Use `other.gameObject.GetComponent` para pegar aquele que você trombou.

**2.**

```
Destroy (gameObject);
```

Você quer tirar vida, ou Destruir o objeto?

**3.**

Lembre-se que há diferença entre usar `gameObject` e `other.gameObject`.

Comment: Ah sim, eu estou usando o mesmo principio desse código em outro jogo, por isso estava tendo dificuldades. Mas consegui resolver mudando o código do PlayerHealth para o script de controle. Agora passou a funcionar certinho. Outro problema que eu estava tendo é em relação a chamar o slider no script, eu consegui de um modo diferente.

Depois eu mando aqui pra você dar uma olhada. Vlw Nils. Seus vídeos são ótimos!